# cakephp magic find function with generic field

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I want this

```
$this->$model_name->findByProgram_id($id)
```

to be executed something like this

```
$this->$model_name->findBy.$field_id($id)
```

where `$field_id = 'program_id` and `$id` is the actual field value.
This is required for dynamically calling function. Will it be possible or i should process with hard-coded field name.

Hope this will make sense!!! 
thanks inn advance

Comment: I wouldn't even use the magic methods in the first place - but stick to the normal find() wrapper methods.

Comment: Check [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types). its very useful if you haven't used it before

Comment: @user1704235 I think mark is familiar with the magic find methods. The 'problem' with those magic methods is that a) they rely on 'magic' `__call()` overloading methods (which causes some overhead) and b) they don't enable you to use the `Containable` behavior. Only using `recursive` to limit what is retrieved is discouraged because most times it will retrieve too much information from the database, which leads to inefficient queries. Using `find(xxx)` and specifying the conditions is often a better way. To prevent messy coding, add your own helper methods to your models

Comment: @user1704235 I had a few minutes of spare time, so added some hints/best practices when retrieving your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using the inflector class in Cakephp,  this is a concept so may need fleshing out but...

```
$methodName = 'findBy' . Inflector:camelize($field_id);

$this->$model_name->$methodName($id);
```

Comment: Thanks @fullybaked. hopefully it won't raise any issues in future :)

Comment: Cool.  _If_ you found this answer useful/helpful can you mark it as answered :)

Comment: Done.. Actually it has some time restriction can only be marked after 10 minute (approx) of posting.

Comment: Thanks :), and learned something new about the time restriction lol

Answer (score 3):

Although the findByXXX magic methods can be convenient at times, they are not always the most efficient way to retrieve your data.

By *no means* I will tell you to completely *avoid* using them, but there are a few things to consider when using them;

### 1. They are 'magic' methods

Magic methods rely on a magic `__call()` method, which (if exists) is called by PHP. I'm not going to start another debate here, as several already [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184337/best-practice-php-magic-methods-set-and-get). Magic methods *does* serve a purpose and can be used in many situations.

Just be aware that;

- they cause (some) overhead (I think this can be ignored in most cases)
- your IDE wont recognise them without additional PhpDoc
- it *may* be less clear for other programmers, because without *knowing* they're magic, they won't be able to find the declaration of the method called (i.e. `findById()` does *not* exist in your source code)

### 2. They don't offer all the functionality that `find(xxx)` offers

CakePHP models may have a lot of 'relations' defined. Although simply calling `Model->find('all')` will give you all the data you need, in most cases it will give you **more than you need**. `Model->find('all')`  in CakePHP is the equivalent of this query in SQL;

```
SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB JOIN tableC.....
```

In other words; it will fetch **all related fields and records** of tableA, tableB and tableC.

In most cases you **don't need** all that data, and queries like this are inefficient, use a lot of memory, and cause your website to perform poorly.

CakePHP has a `recursive` option, that allows you to specify how *deep* to retrieve your data, e.g. By setting `recursive = -1`, CakePHP will only retrieve data from the 'main' table, and not related tables;

```
SELECT * FROM tableA;
```

However, if you want to retrieve data from tableA and tableC but *not* from tableB, you're out of luck when using `recursive`

### Getting Finer control

If you want to have finer control, use the [`Containable behavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). This behavior allows you to specify exactly *which* relations should be included in your results, for example;

```
$this->ModelA->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'ModelA.id',
        'ModelA.name',
        'ModelC.name',
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'ModelC',
    )
));
```

As long as you're not specifying a `contain` key in your `find` options, the ContainableBehavior will not do anything, so it's save to add this behavior by default by adding it to the `$actsAs` array of your AppModel

#### Be specific

Whether you're using the ContainableBehavior or not, being specific is *always* good practice. **Always check the SQL queries that are executed by CakePHP to check if they make sense**. **Always check the *data* that is returned by those queries**; check if they don't contain data that you won't be using.

- Set recursive to `-1` by default in your AppModel (`public $recursive = -1;`). Only set recursive to 1 or 2 if you actually need it. If so, do this on a *per query* basis.
- Use the Containable behavior; it allows you much finer control over what will be retrieved by your queries.
- Always specify exactly the fields that you need. Preferable prefix the fields with the Model-alias to prevent errors if multiple tables in the relation contain fields with the same name (e.g. use `'ModelA.name'` instead of just `'name'`)

### Move data-related logic to your Model - putting it all together

**Try to move all data-related logic/code out of your controller and move it to your Models.**

To get back to your original question; create your own 'convenience' method that allows you to search your model by any field, for example; to enable searching your User Model and retrieve only the id, name and department-name

```
User extends AppModel
{
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public function searchByField($field, $value)
    {
        return $this->find('all',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'User.id',
                    'User.name',
                    'Department.name',
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    // this will dynamically search by $field
                    $field => $value,
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Department',
                )
            )
        );

    }
}
```

This may seem like a lot of code, however, if you become more experienced with CakePHP, methods like this are written in less than 5 minutes. On the plus side; they will give you *full* control over what will be retrieved and can easily be modified to fit your needs.

In your controller, the amount of code is just one line; use it like this;

```
// Search by email
$data = $this->User->searchByField('User.email', 'foo@example.com');

// Search by name
$data = $this->User->searchByField('User.name', 'admin');
```

Comment: Great article!! I will definitely use `Containable behavior`. thanks :)

Comment: @user1704235 please up-vote the answer that fullybaked provided as well. He *did* provide the answer you were looking for in the first place. My 'article' was to provide alternatives and some tips/hints, but his answer is still a *possible* way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I did that already... don't know how its been changed. Anyway I upvoted it again.

Comment: Also as you become more comfortable with CakePHP having methods like theJeztah suggested in your model makes unit tests much easier.

Comment: @fullybaked true, didn't think of mentioning that :)