# Multiplying the returns of 2 methods

Tags: php, methods

I have these two functions:

```
    public function getSales() {
        return $this->sales;
    }
    public function getCommissionRate() {
        return $this->commission_rate;
    }
```

I want to multiply the sales and commission in a new method "getEarnings()" so that I can put it into a variable called $earnings

I am not sure how to make the happen. My best idea is:

```
    public function getEarnings() {
        return $this->sales * $this->commission_rate = $earnings;
    }
```

Can someone please educate me on how to do this correctly?

Comment: Just `return ($this->sales * $this->commission_rate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good coding style says that if you have getters/setters in a class, use them, instead of referencing the variables directly. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351877/should-i-or-should-i-not-use-getter-and-setter-methods) on public variables, getters and setters. The best way is to make your variables private and use their getters and setters, **ALSO**, if you have them, use them from inside the Class too.

So, you could use:

```
// ...
private $earnings;

public function setEarnings() {
    $this->earnings = ($this->getSales() * $this->getCommisionRate());
}

public function getEarnings() {
    return $this->earnings;
}
```

For information purposes, check this [Java post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071407/advantage-of-set-and-get-methods-vs-public-variable) on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use private variables with setters and getters implementation but for the time being here is an example:

```
class example {
    public $this->sales;
    public $this->commission_rate;
    public $this->earnings;

    public function getSales() {
        return $this->sales;
    }
    public function getCommissionRate() {
        return $this->commission_rate;
    }
    public function getEarnings() {
         $this->earnings = $this->sales * $this->commission_rate;
         return $this->earnings;
    }
}
```