# PHP getter and setter

Tags: php, getter

I have a class:

```
class Test
{
    public $AppCount;
    public $Apps;

    // When $AppCount is accessed I want to return count( $this->Apps )
}
```

When I access property `$AppCount`, I want to return `count( $this->Apps )`.

Rather than having to declare an exposing function for this property and making it private, can I use a getter function like C# and Java have?

Obviously the `__get` is not what i want in this case as the property does already exist.

**For the comments**

I have this and it does not run the function when i try and access the property:

```
class ProjectSettingsViewModel
{
    public $ProjectAppCount = 0;
    public $ProjectApps = array();

    public function __get( $property )
    {
        switch( $property )
        {
            case "ProjectAppCount":
                return count( $this->ProjectApps );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If the code seems okay, it must be something else going wrong.

Comment: You can use `__get` with properties that exist

Comment: You *can* use the magic `__get` method for this, but please just create a `Test::getCount()` method. It's called make for a reason

Comment: When i use __get, it does not seem to run when the property exists? I'll provide my code...

Comment: If you want the number of elements in an array, why do you have a property declared? Remove the property and use a magic method, or just use a `getCount()` method.

Comment: 1) It works if you make it `private` / `protected`. 2) That property is useless if you calculate it any way 3) But again. Staph using magic in your code.

Comment: That's the one, cheers. just had to make the property protected/private

Comment: I posted answer, but I second @PeeHaa .. Using magic in your code dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for your concern! The property has to be protected, otherwise the public one overrides it... if you edit your answer to the property being protected then i can accept it... but PeeHaa has the correct answer. I prefer using the getter and setter method, it has a clean markup. and my case is a good case for using it.

Comment: Yep.. Like I said. He is correct. Credits to @PeeHaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested.. Should work though. Using more magic methodology.

```
class ProjectSettingsViewModel
{
    protected $ProjectAppCount = 0;
    public $ProjectApps = array();

    public function __get( $property )
    {
        switch( $property )
        {
            case "ProjectAppCount":
                return count( $this->ProjectApps );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh is this really how PHP handles properties?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No. This is how some developers handle properties. It's not really recommended, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit like the comments on the question explains, magic is bad practice. However, PHP does allow you to do some pretty stupid things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hahaha, touche.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, PHP does not have the getter and setter syntax you are referring to. [It has been proposed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax), but it didn't make it into PHP (yet).

First of all, `__get()` is only executed if you are trying to access a property that can't be accessed (because it is `protected` or `private`, or because it does not exist). If you are calling a property that is `public`, `__get()` will never be executed.

However, I would not suggest using PHP's magic getters and setters unless you really have no other choice. They are slower, tend to become a long if/elseif/else mess very quickly, and code completion (using a smart IDE) will not work. Normal methods are a lot simpler and easier to understand. You should also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6184893/1001110).

I have used the `__get()` and `__set()` methods for a while (instead of manually created `getFoo()` and `setFoo()` methods), because it seemed like a good idea, but I've changed my mind after a short time.

So, in your case, I recommend writing normal methods:

```
<?php

class Test
{
    /**
     * @var App[]
     */
    private $apps;

    /**
     * Returns an array containing all apps
     *
     * @return App[]
     */
    public function getApps()
    {
        return $this->apps;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of apps
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getAppsCount() //or call it countApps()
    {
        return count($this->apps);
    }
}
```