# Handle array of objects in an object

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Given the following two classes, (simplicity for clarity (no sanity-checking of variables etc))

```
<?php
class Person {
    private $Name;
    private $Phones = [];                // List/array of phone number.

    function __construct($name) { $this->__set('Name',    $name);}

    public function __get($property) {return $this->$property;}
    public function __set($property, $value) {$this->$property = $value;}
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
class Phone {
    private $Number;
    private $Type;

    public function __construct($number, $type = "private") {
        $this->__set('Number',         $number);
        $this->__set('Type',           $type);
    }

    public function __get($property) {return $this->$property;}
    public function __set($property, $value) {$this->$property = $value;}
}
?>
```

and the "controller":

```
<?php
    include_once("models/person.inc");
    include_once("models/phone.inc");

    $person = new Person('Tony Test');
    $phone0 = new phone("1234567890", "private");
    $phone1 = new phone("9876543210", "work");
    $phone2 = new phone("3216549870");

    $stack          = array($phone0, $phone1, $phone2);

    // assigning the whole array in one big swoop. Very easy, but not smart.
    $person->Phones  = $stack;

    include_once("views/myview.inc");
?>
```

and last, the unimporatnt view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>person / phone test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1"><tr><td colspan="2">

<?php echo $person->Name; ?></td></tr>

<?php foreach($person->Phones as $val) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $val->Type;   ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $val->Number; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

</table>
<pre><?php echo print_r($person, 1) ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

What would be the best/most logical/smartest way to handle adding/deleting/phone numbers in the person object? If I got my way, I would have the getter and setter handle it, but because it's in an array inside an object, I'm kind of stumped on this. I could off course make indipendant getters/setters for this property, but there are potentionally many of these.

One way I could do it would be letting the `__get()` and `__set()` take in the whole array, while making an special getter and setter for the individual phone object?

Am I heading in the right direction here, or there any other way about this?

Edit: added the view.

Comment: *"...but there are potentionally many of these."* My adivce: Don't be lazy. Every time you obscure your code out of lazyness, it will come to haunt you later.

Comment: I understand completly what you're saying, but I'm willing to work very hard to be lazy. But yeah...

Comment: you should leave `__get()` and `__set()` to php and use `$this->name=$name;` directly in the constructor. as it is now, the way you do it is just... longer without any benefits. `__set()` will be called anyway by php when you define your properties so... yeah, I see no point in what you do

Comment: Moreover, please post the actual code you use. Here, we can tell this is not your real controller (or not your real class) because you try to assign to the private property `phone` while in the public scope. (eg `$person->Phones = $stack;`) The code posted in this question does not run; it throws a visibility error.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier You are wrong about the `__get` and `__set` in the constructor. Try [this code](http://mkw.nisja.net/tests/2/test.txt) and you'll see. It's actually very important.

On the subject of the code in the qestion, it works. I just didn't provide the view, as I deemed it unimportant to the question asked. I'll add it, but it really isn't important in regards to my question.

Comment: @Cavetroll Yeah,  of course if you rewrite __set and __get now you need them, but this smells of bad design. Validation and sanitation should not occur in each class!! Think of the code replication!! Classes are to be built using the data they receive, and your data should be sanitized before being available to build classes from it...

Comment: And in fact what you do not understand is that your magic methods **will be called internally** by php when you use the normal way of setting variables eg `$this->foo = 22` will call `__set()`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier My point is, the magic method **will not be called internally in the class**, as proven by the code I gave in the link i my last comment to you.

Comment: that is because `__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties. `. remove the `private $prop1` in your exemple and `__set()` will be called. (since in your exemple there is no else for when the property does not exist, it will just remove prop1 from the var_dump) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Best practice: PHP Magic Methods __set and __get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184337/best-practice-php-magic-methods-set-and-get)

Perhaps magic methods are not the way.

Also, you could create the methods addPhone, removePhone, etc. They would simply iterate over the array and to their job or push a new phone to the list.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best/most logical/smartest way to handle adding/deleting/phone numbers in the person object?

I think that would be encapsulate it by it's different parts (as I see them)

#### gathering phone data

I assume this is a simplified example and your data is not hardcoded; it comes from whatever, maybe a database, so format it however you like, maybe this:

```
$phoneContainer = array(
  0=>array("1234567890","private"),
  1=>array("9876543210","work"),
  2=>array("3216549870"),
);
```

#### creating the objects

```
new phone($number,$group); // yeah obviously thanks Felix
```

#### ... while iterating the container

```
foreach ($phoneContainer as $phoneInfo) {
  if (isset($phoneInfo[1])) $phone = new phone($phoneInfo[0],$phoneInfo[1]);
  else $phone = new phone($phoneInfo[0]);
  $person->phones[] = $phone;
}
```

---

however, directly using public properties to set an array of objects is questionable. I would at least consider such a property in the `person` class, and it's usage:

```
public function addToGroup($group,$what) {
  $this->$group[] = $what;
}
// now in the foreach:
$person->addToGroup('phones',$phone);
```

you can use this same function to manage potentially a good part of all your `potentionally many of these`, all those that react as containers at least.

---

unrelated, but [php has some reserved usage for `__set()` and `__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Why not just define them as normal set and get?

```
public function get($property) {return $this->$property;}
public function set($property, $value) {$this->$property = $value;}
```

they are no less your own functions with which you can sanitize or validate data as you wish, but they are also not anymore in php's way.